# Primefaces - Añadir fila a datatable con AJAX y variable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, java-ee, java-8

Tengo un gran problema a la hora de añadir una fila a un datatable con Primefaces, solo que no lo hago desde la base de datos sino a traves de una variable tipo List porque a traves de dicha lista enviare los datos para ser registrados, pero no logro hacer que se actualice. Probe con la solucion que propocionan aqui: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21517327/...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21517327/update-primefaces-datatable-with-new-rows-adding-dynamically)

Pero no logro hacer que funcione para un ViewScoped ya que no se invoca el metodo que añade una fila a la lista.

Adjunto el codigo para ver si es que no entiendo el funcionamiento de AJAX o es algo de mi codigo.

Pagina de registro:

```
<ui:composition xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
                template="./../WEB-INF/plantilla.xhtml"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">

    <ui:define name="titulo">
        Añadir Materia
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="breadcrumbs">
        <li><p:link outcome="listamaterias">Materias</p:link></li>
        <li>/</li>
        <li>Nueva Materia</li>
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="contenido">
        <div class="ui-g ui-fluid">
            <div class="ui-g-12">
                <div class="card">
                    <h:form id="formMateria">
                        <p:panelGrid layout="grid" columns="4" columnClasses="ui-g-2,ui-g-6,ui-g-2,ui-g-6" styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank">
                            <p:outputLabel value="Nombre: "/>
                            <p:inputText />
                            <p:outputLabel value="Horas Teoricas Semanales: " />
                            <p:spinner />

                            <p:outputLabel value="Cantidad de UV: " />
                            <p:spinner />
                            <p:outputLabel value="Horas Practicas Semanales: " />
                            <p:spinner />                            
                        </p:panelGrid>
                        <p:panelGrid layout="grid" columns="7" styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank">
                            <p:outputLabel value="Carrera: " />
                            <p:selectOneMenu value="#{nuevaMateriaBean.carreraSelected}" converter="#{carreraConverter}" style="width: 100%;">
                                <f:selectItems value="#{nuevaMateriaBean.carrerasList}" var="carrera" itemLabel="#{carrera.nombre}" itemValue="#{carrera}" />
                            </p:selectOneMenu>
                            <p:outputLabel value="Pensum: " />
                            <p:selectOneMenu value="#{nuevaMateriaBean.pensumSelected}" converter="#{pensumConversor}" style="width: 100%;">
                                <f:selectItems value="#{nuevaMateriaBean.pensumsList}" var="pensum" itemLabel="#{pensum.año}" itemValue="#{pensum}" />
                            </p:selectOneMenu>
                            <p:outputLabel value="Ciclo: " />
                            <p:selectOneMenu value="#{nuevaMateriaBean.cicloSelected}" converter="#{cicloAcademicoConverter}" style="width: 100%;">
                                <f:selectItems value="#{nuevaMateriaBean.ciclosList}" var="ciclo" itemLabel="#{ciclo.numero}" itemValue="#{ciclo}" />
                            </p:selectOneMenu>
                            <p:commandButton value="A&ntilde;adir a la lista"
                                             update="@form"
                                             actionListener="#{nuevaMateriaBean.addDetalle()}"
                                             process="@form"
                                             icon="ui-icon-plus"/>

                        </p:panelGrid>

                        <p:dataTable id="dtDetalles"
                                     value="#{nuevaMateriaBean.detallesRegistro}"
                                     var="detalle"
                                     selectionMode="single"
                                     reflow="true"
                                     paginator="true"
                                     rows="5"

                                     emptyMessage="No se han encontrado datos">
                            <p:column headerText="Carrera">
                                <h:outputText value="#{detalle.carrera.nombre}" />
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column headerText="Pensum">
                                <h:outputText value="#{detalle.pensum.año}" />
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column headerText="Ciclo">
                                <h:outputText value="#{detalle.cicloAcademico.numero}"/>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column headerText="¿Eliminar?">
                                <p:commandButton title="Eliminar" class="red-btn" icon="ui-icon-delete" />
                            </p:column>
                        </p:dataTable>
                    </h:form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Codigo del managedbean:

```
@Named(value = "nuevaMateriaBean")
@ViewScoped
public class NuevaMateriaWebBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7373901675189897283L;

    //Componentes
    private String nombre;
    private Integer uv;
    private Integer semanas;
    private Integer horas;
    private CarrerasDTO carreraSelected;
    private Pensum pensumSelected;
    private CicloAcademico cicloSelected;
    private List<CarrerasDTO> carrerasList;
    private List<Pensum> pensumsList;
    private List<CicloAcademico> ciclosList;
    private List<DetalleMateria> detallesRegistro;

    //EJB
    @EJB(lookup = Constantes.JDNI_CARRERAS_BEAN)
    private CarrerasBeanLocal carrerasBean;
    @EJB(lookup = Constantes.JDNI_PENSUM_BEAN)
    private PensumBeanLocal pensumBean;
    @EJB(lookup = Constantes.JDNI_CICLO_ACADEMICO_BEAN)
    private CicloAcademicoBeanLocal cicloAcademicoBean;
    //Variables
    private MateriaDTO materia;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        try {
            carrerasList = carrerasBean.obtenerCarreras();
            pensumsList = pensumBean.obtenerPensums();
            ciclosList = cicloAcademicoBean.obtenerCiclosAcademicos();
            detallesRegistro = new ArrayList<>();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public Integer getUv() {
        return uv;
    }

    public void setUv(Integer uv) {
        this.uv = uv;
    }

    public Integer getSemanas() {
        return semanas;
    }

    public void setSemanas(Integer semanas) {
        this.semanas = semanas;
    }

    public Integer getHoras() {
        return horas;
    }

    public void setHoras(Integer horas) {
        this.horas = horas;
    }

    public CarrerasDTO getCarreraSelected() {
        return carreraSelected;
    }

    public void setCarreraSelected(CarrerasDTO carreraSelected) {
        this.carreraSelected = carreraSelected;
    }

    public Pensum getPensumSelected() {
        return pensumSelected;
    }

    public void setPensumSelected(Pensum pensumSelected) {
        this.pensumSelected = pensumSelected;
    }

    public CicloAcademico getCicloSelected() {
        return cicloSelected;
    }

    public void setCicloSelected(CicloAcademico cicloSelected) {
        this.cicloSelected = cicloSelected;
    }

    public List<CarrerasDTO> getCarrerasList() {
        return carrerasList;
    }

    public void setCarrerasList(List<CarrerasDTO> carrerasList) {
        this.carrerasList = carrerasList;
    }

    public List<Pensum> getPensumsList() {
        return pensumsList;
    }

    public void setPensumsList(List<Pensum> pensumsList) {
        this.pensumsList = pensumsList;
    }

    public List<CicloAcademico> getCiclosList() {
        return ciclosList;
    }

    public void setCiclosList(List<CicloAcademico> ciclosList) {
        this.ciclosList = ciclosList;
    }

    public List<DetalleMateria> getDetallesRegistro() {
        return detallesRegistro;
    }

    public void setDetallesRegistro(List<DetalleMateria> detallesRegistro) {
        this.detallesRegistro = detallesRegistro;
    }

    public void addDetalle() {
        DetalleMateria nuevo = new DetalleMateria();
        Carrera carrera = carrerasBean.findByIdEntity(carreraSelected.getIdCarrera());
        nuevo.setCarrera(carrera);
        nuevo.setPensum(pensumSelected);
        nuevo.setCicloAcademico(cicloSelected);
        detallesRegistro.add(nuevo);
    }

}
```

Adicional:

- Primefaces 6.1
- JSF 2.2
- Java EE 7
- Wildfly 11
- Tambien cabe mencionar que cuando doy click en el boton que invoca la funcion por ajax se ponen en color rojo los selectOneMenu y no me lanza ninguna exception.

Comment: Como consejo solo utiliza un ejb para todas las tablas, solo en caso q sean base de datos diferentes entonces si hazlo así como lo tienes

Answer (score 0):

Bueno me respondo a mi mismo, ya que en transcurso del dia hice otras prueba, y descubir que el CustomConverter que uso en uno de los selectOneMany no funcionaba porque la clase a la que se convierte no tenia un equals()